# inserting facebook meta tags in the code rather than statically in html page does not work as expected

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having a strange issue regarding to the facebook meta tags.'

when I add them directly to the html page and when I post my page url to facebook, facebook is able to read through the meta tags in my page:

```
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://s3.amazonaws.com/test/58474 
 4/mobile/scott_plus_malcolm.jpg">

  <meta id="testtttt33" property="og:url" content="....story/100749714">
  <meta property="og:type" content="article">
   <meta property="og:title" content="2222222222222222222222">
```

However when I do the the same in react app as follows:

```
    componentWillMount(){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    head.insertBefore(createMetaTag("fb:app_id","204184740523601"), head.firstElementChild);
    head.insertBefore(createMetaTag("og:description","xxxxx"), head.firstElementChild);
    head.insertBefore(createMetaTag("og:title","xxxx"), head.firstElementChild);
    head.insertBefore(createMetaTag("og:type","article"), head.firstElementChild);
    head.insertBefore(createMetaTag("og:url","/story/100749714"), head.firstElementChild);
    head.insertBefore(createMetaTag("og:image","https://s3.amazonaws.com/resized.images.stg2.xxx.com/584744/mobile/scott_plus_malcolm.jpg"), head.firstElementChild);
    console.log("wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww");
    console.log(head);
}


 export function createMetaTag(property,content) {
    var meta = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.property = property;
    meta.setAttribute('property', property);
    meta.content = content;
    return meta;
}
```

Also it is noteworthy that I already tried the following as well but did not get anywhere:

```
                <Helmet>
                    <meta id="testtttt1112" property="og:image" content="https://s3.amazonaws.com/resized.images.stg2.xxxx.com/584744/mobile/scott_plus_malcolm.jpg"/>
                    <meta id="testtttt2223" property="og:url" content="https://stg3.xxxxx/story/100749714"/>
                    <meta id="testtttt3334" property="og:type" content="article"/>
                    <meta id="testtttt5555" property="og:title" content="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"/>
                    <meta id="testtttt6666" property="og:description" content="wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww dddddddddddddddddddd gggggggggggggggggggggggggggg hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"/>
                    <meta id="testtttt7777" property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxx"/>
                </Helmet>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Said here countless times already … The Facebook scraper does NOT care for any client-side JavaScript. The _initial_ HTML your server returns when the URL is requested, must contain these meta tags, _everything else_ will NOT work.

Comment: @04FS so what should I do in a case when we need to update metatags based on the content we load using ajax in a single page app? If we hard code it then what is the point of that?

Comment: There are services like prerender.io that can help with this. (I know that works for Angular for example, if it works for react apps as well, go check.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook ignores JavaScript, you HAVE to make sure the tags are visible in the initial source. There are different ways to solve this, for example:

- SSR - Server Side Rendering (For example, with [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/))
- https://prerender.io/

Answer (score 0):

I think can be achieve with react serverside rendering please check it pretty simple and load all meta data on before page render